# Move mysql data from rows to a pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've a table products with:

```
ID | shop_id | ...
```

I wanto to convert **id <-> shop_id relations** to a pivot table and I need a query to avoid to make this job manually.

My pivot table product_shop have:

```
ID | product_id | shop_id
```

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE**

I've in **product** table this rows:

```
id | shop_id | name
1  | 4       | Tablet Samsung
3  | 10      | Iphone
```

I need to populate my brand new pivot table **product_shop** (now empty) with:

```
ID | product_id | shop_id
1  | 1          | 4
2  | 3          | 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your database structure, along with the expected results? The information you have provided is not enough to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Try this : 
`INSERT INTO product_shop (product_id ,shop_id)
SELECT id ,shop_id FROM product  ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your schema and sample
assuming you have the pivot table product_shop  with

```
  id autoincrement,
  product_id,
  shop_id
```

you could use a insert select

```
 insert into product_shop (  product_id,   shop_id )
 select id, shop_id 
 from product
```